# Can I run VS2008 Team System Load Test scenarios sequentially?

Tags: load-testing, webtest

I have a couple of load test scenarios composed of several web tests in Visual Studio 2008 Ultimate. By default these scenarios are run concurrently - is there some way to run them sequentially, such that the first test runs for some duration, then the second scenario runs for the same duration?

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward approach would be to create a coded web test that yields a different set of tests after a certain time.

Though this approach would be a bit labour intensive in re-arranging the code to do what you want.

I have to admit some curiosity as to why you would want to do this?